# When I print the element of list, the output is strange

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
l = ['cd\xd9>+O\x17 \xafbQ\x85\x86\xaaPo\xd8m',   'cd\xc3k\x9b\x1d\x08\x84MXr0!\xd1\xec\x86\xab\x01', 'cw\x1c\x9e\x08\x05`\x8f\x9dfd\xd0\xbfS7\x9dZ\x8f']
print l[0]
```

and the output is

[image]

Why is the output so strange?
I hope when I print `l[0]`, I can see `'cd\xd9>+O\x17 \xafbQ\x85\x86\xaaPo\xd8m'`, what should I do?

Comment: Are you sure you want `'cd\x9'` and not `'cd\\x9'`?

Comment: Yes, you should change your list elements to look like mine (note the double backslash). Also, you can use backticks (the `\`` key, to the left of the `1` key) to display code in comments.

Comment: sure,I get the string from other place ,and put them in a list,then I want to print the element one by one ,I found I can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `\` with `\\` as shown

```
l = ['cd\\xd9>+O\\0x17 \\xafbQ\\x85\\x86\\xaaPo\\xd8m',   'cd\\xc3k\\x9b\\x1d\
\x08\\x84MXr0!\\xd1\\xec\\x86\\xab\\x01', 'cw\\x1c\\x9e\\x08\\x05`\\x8f\\x9dfd\\
xd0\\xbfS7\\x9dZ\\x8f']

print l[0]
cd\xd9>+O\x17 \xafbQ\x85\x86\xaaPo\xd8m
```

Comment: How to replace? I use l[0].replace('\\x','\\\\x'), it can't work

Comment: A much simpler fix is to change the string to a raw string.  Where you have `l = ['cd` change it to `l = [r'cd`... and similarly add a `r` prefix to your other strings.

Comment: Since there are almost 1000 elements in the list , so how to add a 'r' by using code?

Comment: I found the function repr(object) may be used to this kind of situation

Answer (score 0):

`\x**` corresponds to a non-printable ASCII character, though depending on your terminal settings, it may try to print it anyway, which is why you're getting the garbled characters.

Comment: Thanks for your answers , it makes me understand the cause of the problem .  I now is to find a way to solve it